# converting video to NSData in share extension in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, nsurlsession, youtube-data-api

I have created a share extension for my ios app. When I click on the share option in the photo app my share extension is shown and I click on it and my controller is shown. Everything is working fine up to this. I am uploading video to youtube using the youtube api. I am using this method to create the parameter

```
GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:fileData MIMEType:@"video/*"];
```

Now if the video is small then it is easily converted to NSData using this code

```
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoURL]];
```

and everything is working and video is uploaded.

But if the video is large then it simply crash and exit from the share extension(I put breakpoint and found this problem. If I remove the fileData conversion then its not crashing.). So what I did was instead of converting it to NSData I used this youtube api method

```
GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithFileURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoURL] MIMEType:@"video/*"];
```

Now app is not crashing but I am getting network error. The error is

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-995 "(null)"

little searching found that it is because of NSURLSession and told to use something like this

```
sessionConfiguration.sharedContainerIdentifier = @“com.me.myapp.containerIdentifier”;
```

I am using youtube api. I am not sure where to use it OR is there any other way to use youtube api in share extension with large video file.

**NOTE**: I am using youtube api in my app and its working fine with NSData.

Hope question is clear. I am stuck on it for a day now. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1:

I used this code

```
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoURL] options:0 error:&error];
```

filedata is nil. The error I am getting is

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “IMG_2187.MOV”
>   couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."
>   UserInfo={NSFilePath=/file:/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/102APPLE/IMG_2187.MOV,

Comment: The `NSURLErrorBackgroundSessionRequiresSharedContainer` (which is what the `-995` error is) makes me suspect that the background service doesn't like like referencing something outside of your container. Perhaps try copying it to your documents or temp folder and then uploading with `uploadParametersWithFileURL` using the fileURL from there.

Comment: FWIW, it looks like this is where Sergey was going in his answer...

Answer (score 2):

1. Consider this line:

   ```
   var videoDataURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL!
   ```

   This does a forced unwrapping of `info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]` (which is bad, because if it was `nil`, the app would crash) and that casts it as an implicitly unwrapped optional `NSURL!`. That doesn't make sense. Just do a conditional unwrapping (and unwrap to a `NSURL`, not a `NSURL!`):

   ```
   if let videoDataURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL { ... }
   ```
2. The next line calls `filePathURL`:

   ```
   var videoFileURL = videoDataURL.filePathURL
   ```

   If you wanted a file URL, you already have one, so no conversion is needed, but instead just use `videoDataURL`. If you really wanted a path, you'd use `path` method:

   ```
   let videoPath = videoDataURL.path
   ```

   Frankly, Apple is trying to shift us away from using string paths, so just use the original `videoDataURL` and avoid the use of both path and `filePathURL`.
3. You are using `dataWithContentsOfMappedFile`:

   ```
   var video = NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile("\(videoDataURL)")
   ```

   If you really wanted to use `dataWithContentsOfMappedFile`, the proper Swift syntax is:

   ```
   let video = NSData(contentsOfMappedFile: videoPath!)
   ```

   But `dataWithContentsOfMappedFile` deprecated, so you should instead use:

   ```
   let video = try NSData(contentsOfFile: videoPath!, options:   .DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
   ```

   Or, bypassing that `videoPath` altogether, you could:

   ```
   let video3 = try NSData(contentsOfURL: videoDataURL, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
   ```

   Obviously, those try renditions should be done within a do block with a catch block.
4. By the way, as you'll see in all of my above examples, one should use `let` where possible.

Quite frankly, I would advise against loading it into a `NSData` at all. Just copy it with `NSFileManager`, which is a more efficient use of memory. If the video is long, it could be quite large, and you should avoid loading the whole thing into memory at any given point in time.

So you could:

```
if let videoDataURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL {
    do {
        // build your destination URL however you want
        //
        // let tempFolder = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
        // let destinationURL = tempFolder.URLByAppendingPathComponent("test.mov")

        // or 

        let documents = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false)
        let destinationURL = documents.URLByAppendingPathComponent("test.mov")

        // but just copy from the video URL to the destination URL

        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtURL(videoDataURL, toURL: destinationURL)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

If you're uploading this to a web service, you'd then use a `NSURLSessionUploadTask`, using file or stream options. The construction of this request is a separate question, but hopefully you get the idea: With large assets like photos or, especially, videos, don't instantiate a `NSData` with the asset if you can possibly avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this if your file exist in your phone instead of [NSURL URLWithString:videoURL].

NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoURL]];

Comment: I did fileData returns nil

Comment: could you log the videoURL?

Comment: this is videoURL file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/102APPLE/IMG_2187.MOV

Comment: Updates the question

Comment: if you use your code [NSURL URLWithString:videoURL], fileData is nil ?

Comment: it crashes as the file is large.

Comment: His `videoURL` starts with `file:///`, so therefore `fileURLWithPath` is incorrect. It's not a path. It's a URL string. `URLWithString` is the correct syntax. But you can't do `dataWithContentsOfURL` because the asset is simply too large.